# Adding list items from prompt and save them after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am helping a friend with a website that they are trying to make and I am trying to add an admin button that will allow them to click the button to add/delete the car description, picture, and price. I also need them to stay on the page after the page reloads. What is the best way of going about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cars</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Items</h1>

    <ul id="items">

        <li><span>Delete</span></li>
        
    </ul>
    
    <button type="button" id="add-item">Add item</button>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

ul {
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    align-items: center;
}

li > span {
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

let addButton = document.getElementById("add-item");

const curIndex = 0;

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
     // Retrieves the 'list'
     let list = document.getElementById("items");
     let textNode = window.prompt("Enter item:");
     if (textNode != null) {
         let item = document.createElement("li");
         //Creates a textnode from the users input
         item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textNode));
         //Adds the users textnode at the end of the list
         list.appendChild(item);
         // Creates a delete button 
         let deleteButton = document.createElement("span");
         deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete"
         item.appendChild(deleteButton)
     }
});
```

Comment: Well if you reload the page, it reloads the same page anyway, so that's not an issue in itself. Are you actually asking how to persist the data changes that have been made and show those changes next time the page is loaded? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Apologies, yes that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Traditionally you'd submit the data to the server via a form and save it into a database. And you have some code which fetches that data when the page (or a different page if you like) is loaded again. Or if you only need this to function in one browser you could do it all entirely client-side using localstorage - the disadvantage of that is that others loading the page on another computer (or even another browser) can't see the data that someone else made.

Answer (score 1):

**One**

It looks like you are trying to maintain a list on the browser where the user can add and delete the items.  In which case you need to use a form and a submit button which will execute the PHP file again (or a different file as required).  At that point in the server, you can save it to the database or file.

**Two**

If you are trying to save each entry as it's added, then you need to abandon your whole javascript code.  And provide a form with an input and an add-button.  This will submit the form and you can save the entry.

For delete to work, you need to populate the form with all the saved values and have a button next to each value to delete that value.  Each button needs to have a unique id/name so that you can detect which item you want to delete.

There are other ways of doing it too.